# Why is this glsl shader causing an "Invalid Operation" when trying to use the program?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm checking the logs, and everything compiles fine. The shader looks like this:

Vertex:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in struct InData {
    vec3 position;
    vec4 color;
} inData;
out struct OutData {
    vec3 position;
    vec4 color;
} outData;
void main()
{  
    outData.position = inData.position;
    outData.color = inData.color;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
in struct InData {
    vec2 position;
    vec4 color;
} inData;
out vec4 color;
void main(){
    color = inData.color;
}
```

I'm preparing the shader like this:

```
    public Shader(string src, ShaderType type)
    {

        shaderId = GL.CreateShader(type);
        GL.ShaderSource(shaderId, GetShader(src));
        GL.CompileShader(shaderId);
        EventSystem.Log.Message(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shaderId));
        EventSystem.Log.Message("GLERROR: " + GL.GetError());
        packs = new List<ShaderPack>();
    }
    public void Attach(ShaderPack pack)
    {
        packs.Add(pack);
        GL.AttachShader(pack.ProgramID, shaderId);
        EventSystem.Log.Message(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(pack.ProgramID));
        EventSystem.Log.Message("GLERROR: " + GL.GetError());
    }
```

Then I compile the shader:

```
    public void Compile()
    {
        if(program >= 0)
            GL.DeleteProgram(program);
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        foreach (var s in shaders.Values)
            s.Attach(this);
        EventSystem.Log.Message(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(program));
        EventSystem.Log.Message("GLERROR: " + GL.GetError());
    }
```

And then I'm trying to use it:

```
        mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.AddTriangle(
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1),
            new Vector3(0, sizeY, 0), new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 1),
            new Vector3(sizeX, sizeY, 0), new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 1));
        mesh.RefreshBuffer();
        
        shaderPack.Apply();
        shaderPack.SetVertexAttribute<Mesh.MeshData1>("vertex", 0, mesh.meshData);
        EventSystem.Log.Message("GLERROR: " + GL.GetError());
```

In Apply GL.UseProgram is called and GetError returns "Invalid Operation"

UPDATE:

Okay I changed the code:

```
    public void Compile()
    {
        if(program >= 0)
            GL.DeleteProgram(program);
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        foreach (var s in shaders.Values)
            s.Attach(this);
       // GL.LinkProgram(program);
        //GL.ValidateProgram(program);

        GL.ValidateProgram(program);
        EventSystem.Log.Message("Validate: " + GL.GetProgramInfoLog(program) + " - " + GL.GetError());
    }
    public void Apply()
    {
        
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        EventSystem.Log.Message("GLERROR (Apply): " + GL.GetError());
    }
```

And the output is

> [23:25:55][Log]: Validate:  - NoError
>
> [23:25:55][Log]: GLERROR (Apply): InvalidOperation

edit: Okay I changed the vertex shaders:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in struct InData {
    vec3 position;
    vec4 color;
} inData;
void main()
{  
    gl_Position = vec4(inData.position, 1);
}
```

...

```
#version 330 core
//in struct InData {
//    vec2 position;
//    vec4 color;
//} inData;
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

It compiles without errors, but I have a blank screen...

#### Pre-Rollback:

---

EDIT: Okay, I suspect the problem lies here:

```
    public void VertexAttribute<T>(int loc, ShaderPack p, T[] dataArray) where T : struct
    {
        int buf;
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out buf);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buf);
        GL.BufferData<T>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(dataArray.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))), dataArray, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer<T>(loc, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, ref dataArray[0]);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

    }
```

I'm passing this with an Array of the following type:

```
    public struct MeshData1
    {
        public Vector3 vertex;
        public Vector4 color;
        public MeshData1(Vector3 vertex, Vector4 color)
        {
            this.vertex = vertex;
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
```

And the input looks like this:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in struct InData {
    vec3 position;
    vec4 color;
} inData;
void main()
{  
    gl_Position = vec4(inData.position, 1.0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because you never linked the shader stages... you only attached them. For that matter, `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` will not produce anything meaningful until ***after*** you either 1) link your program or 2) validate your program. You have done neither.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. Edit: Damn, now I have a blank screen :(

Comment: Your vertex shader's output interface block is incorrect as well. You need to output the position as a `vec4`, and unless you are using a geometry shader you are required to write to `gl_Position` if you want something to show up on screen. Are you following a tutorial by any chance? There are a lot of weird things in these two shaders.

Comment: Thanks Andon, but gl_Position is not available in core mode right? Or do I have to implement ALL shaders in core mode ? edit: Also vec4 ? so vec4(input.position, 1) ?

Comment: `gl_Position` is not only available, it is the one thing you are required to write in at least one vertex transformation stage (vertex shader, geometry shader, tessellation) for anything to show up on screen. As for `vec4`, this is necessary because after vertex transformation the next step is a homogenous divide -- your vertex becomes: vertex / vertex.w. Go ahead and declare the input position as `vec4` to make everything easier, GLSL will automatically make `w` 1.0 if you supply a 3 component vertex attribute pointer to a 4 component attribute...

Comment: Wow, thanks. It's compiling now, I just still have a blank screen.

Comment: Now the problem is probably because you are not using any transformation matrices. The vertex shader is supposed to output a clip-space position, which has an XYZ range [-1,1] for all visible points. Usually you multiply by some matrix to go from model-space to clip-space, but you could use vertex coordinates in the range discussed above. Anyway, this is turning into a completely different question and the comments are getting lengthy - I would suggest you read a good OpenGL 3.2+ core GLSL tutorial. [Arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Positioning.html) would be a start

Comment: Please do not edit your question the way you just did. Now the answer I wrote originally has no context, and the title does not make any sense either. You should consider rolling-back the update and possibly asking a new question, because it is a completely different question from what was answered now.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems immediately come to mind:

1. You never linked the attached shader stages in your program object (**most important**)
2. The string output by [`glGetProgramInfoLog (...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInfoLog.xhtml) is only generated/updated after linking or validating a GLSL program.

To fix this, you should make a call to [`glLinkProgram (...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLinkProgram.xhtml) after attaching your shaders, and also understand that up until you do this the program info log will be undefined.

---

[`glValidateProgram (...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glValidateProgram.xhtml) is another way of updating the contents of the program info log. In addition to generating the info log, this function will also return whether your program is in a state suitable for execution or not. The result of this operation is stored in a per-program state called `GL_VALIDATE_STATUS`.

Comment: @user1071988: I must not have made it clear enough, linking is ***not*** an optional operation. Uncomment the LinkProgram line from your updated question and the problem should go away. Also, the status of validation is not indicated by `glGetError (...)`. The status is determined by calling `glGetProgramiv (...)` with `GL_VALIDATE_STATUS` -- it will be `GL_TRUE` if valid, `GL_FALSE` otherwise.